# How do I change the hold delay to move a Unity launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, dock

I need to increase the hold delay to move an icon in the Unity launcher in Ubuntu 13.10. How do I do that ?

I need this because of latency of remote desktop access: a short click acts as a long one in the server/distant machine, and so I can't launch/select an application from the dock.

Comment: Have you try unity-tweak-tools ? I'm not sure if this option is in it, but it's worse the try !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild the unity source after finding where and how the duration from 'open' to 'grab' is set. This may prove simple or complex.

As a starter will point you to one possible area to check `/launcher/Launcher.cpp`, line #76 (or thereabouts, looking in current 14.04 unity source, times are in ms):

```
const int START_DRAGICON_DURATION = 250;
```

As far as rebuilding, installing unity source - strongly advise doing as Debian packages the same way as Ubuntu does. Possibly another question as how to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using `gsettings` to change `grab-wait` in `com.canonical.Unity.Decorations` is what you want.

This value is described as:

> Milliseconds to wait before considering a mouse pressure a grab

### On the command line

You can read your current setting:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Decorations grab-wait
```

You can set it:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Decorations grab-wait 1000
```

### In a GUI

Alternatively, you can install the gui `dconf-editor` and use that.